# Error con IF syntax no valid

Tags: python, python-3.x

estoy creando esta funcion en Python:

```
def myThreshold(I,p):
    Ibn = I;
    if((p > 0) && (p < 256))
    index = find(I >= p);
    lbn = lbn * 0;
    lbn(index) = 255;

    return lbn
```

pero en la linea del if aparece un error que dice que la sintaxis no es valida, ¿En que estoy fallando?

Gracias

Comment: Te faltan los `:` después del `if`, ademas  en vez de `&&` debes usar `and` aunque deberías hacer simplemente `if 0 < p < 256:` y recuerda que Python usa identación para delimitar los bloques de código, los `;` son irrelevantes ahí. ¿Qué es `lbl `? Porque no estoy seguro de que `lbn(index) = 255` sea correcto...

Comment: 1. te faltan los dos puntos `:` al final de esa linea, 2. Cambia `&&` por `and` 3. no son necesarias los `;`, 3. revisa la indentación

Comment: Es una funcion para umbralizar una imagen y digamos que si cargo una imagen de unas monedas,en la imagen se deben ver las monedas pero sin el fondo. Lo que comentaste lo apliqué y me ayudo, gracias...

Comment: @BasilioSaldarriaga Python tiene una sintaxis distinta :-), muchas veces cuando usamos otro lenguaje pensamos que la sintaxis es la misma pero no lo es :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta algo como lo siguiente:

```
def myThreshold(I,p):
    Ibn = I                   # <-- ?
    if 0 < p < 256:
        index = find(I >= p)
        lbn = lbn * 0         # <-- ?
        lbn(index) = 255      # <-- ?
    return lbn
```

Aunque `lbn(index)` está siendo llamado como si fuera una función, sin embargo, en la línea anterior asignas un valor que, en caso de albergar un número (`int` o `float`) `lbn` se convertíría en cero.

Asimismo, estás declarando la variable `Ibn` dentro del cuerpo de la función y en ninguna otra línea la utilizas.

Comment: si cambias `if((p > 0) and (p < 256)):` a  `if 0 < p < 256 :` la respuesta será más legible

Comment: De acuerdo, edité la respuesta para que refleje esta mejora en sintaxis.